# Jquery $.getJSON adds script tag to head

Tags: jquery, web-services, getjson

I was just debugging something and I noticed whenever I call a webservice with $.getJson from my plugin the webservice url gets added a script tag in the head of the html for a split seconds and then dissappears again. The script tag also has the async property.

Is this normal behaviour ?

```
$.getJSON(options.url, function(data) {
                self.Address = data;
                self.AddressWSCallback();
            });
```

Comment: Is this a cross domain call? url == cross domain?

Comment: Yeah it is but I am adding {url: url + "?callback=?"} to the url

Comment: Do I have to add jsonp as well to this ?

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery Cookbook by Cody Lindley

If the request is cross-domain, jQuery will automatically treat this request as a JSONP and fill in the appropriate callback function name. This also means that jQuery will initiate the request by inserting a  tag into the document instead of using XMLHttpRequest object.

[Cross-Domain requests in javascript](https://jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/)
JSONP relies on the fact that  tags can have sources coming from different origins. When the browser parses a  tag, it will GET the script content (residing on any origin) and execute it in the current page’s context. Normally, a service would return HTML or some data represented in a data format like XML or JSON. When a request is made to a JSONP-enabled server however, it returns a script block that executes a callback function the calling page has specified, supplying the actual data as an argument.

Comment: So there is nothing I can do there then, it's fine ? The webservice call is cross domain and I am adding callback parameter to url

Comment: It needs to execute the callback by the origin page. See my updated answer

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you give an example ?

Comment: When you make a cross domain call, it needs to execute your callback. The browser will have to return the script block that contains your callback (GET). As a result, it insert a script tag into the document.

Comment: So this is normal behaviour, and nothing more I can do about it ? Also I noticed if i get a 404 results it just stays in the <head>

Comment: Failed requests don't get cleared automatically and you have to do that yourself with something like this: 

$('head script[src*="callback="]').remove();